# yocto-bitbake mirror keep branch

Tags: yocto, bitbake

for my yocto project I'm mirroring to my repo to a private one, it's working fine for basic SRC_URI, but for url that have a branch defined it will erase it and bring the default one (master), making it fail since the branch referenced in the original uri was a tag.
`DEBUG: Fetcher failure: Unable to find revision xxx_git_commit_hash_xxx in branch master even from upstream`

In my .bb file:

`SRC_URI = "git://github.com/google/protobuf.git;branch=3.11.x \`

and in my local.conf (in the build folder) for the mirroring i have:

```
SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR="myUser@MyServerIdServer:/The/Path/to/directory"
PREMIRRORS_prepend ?= "\
git://.*/.* git://${SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR}/HOST/PATH;protocol=ssh\n \
"
```

(Yes i want to keep HOST and PATH as path to get the repo)
I can see in the logs that my repo is correctly fetch, but the "new" url is without branch and I can't find a way to keep the .bb one

I tried to [understand](https://www.mndet.net/2018/12/28/yocto-mirrors.html) and look at the [documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#source-mirrors), but i don't see a way to keep a specific parameter (like the HOST and PATH variable)
So i tried to look at the **init**.py which define the rules, but i couldn't figure out if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right notation would be specifying the branch as well into the premirror URL.

```bash
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL = "git://${SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR};protocol=ssh;branch=3.11.x"
PREMIRRORS_prepend = " git://.*/.*     ${SOURCE_MIRROR_URL} \
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did work,i didn't need premirror_prepend, here's mine :

```
SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR="myUser@MyServerIdServer:/The/Path/to/directory"
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL="git://${SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR}/HOST/PATH;protocol=ssh"
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"
```

And if i want to add new url mirror i can use Mirror

```
MIRRORS += "\
git://.*/.*     ${SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR_2}/HOST/PATH \n \
https?$://.*/.* ${SOURCE_TOMYMIRROR_2}/HOST/PATH \n \
"
```